# Change the location of UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIPageViewController` and I want to change the location of the `UIPageControl` in which I can choose any location I prefer in my App layout , also How can change the style like the color ,the shape "squares not circles" and page indicator alignment ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't implement the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` presentation count and index methods, the default `UIPageControl` won't be drawn.  Then you can just create your own `UIPageControl` and add it as another subview.  Then in the other delegate methods you can update which one is selected.  And now you have full control over the position and colors and such, since you own the control.

Comment: Those methods are part of the datasource not the delegate.